# Windows Azure Website - Block IP Range

Tags: windows, azure, web-config, ip, block

I need to block everything besides an IP range at my Windows Azure website, but unfortunately I can't really figure it out.

My Web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false"><!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
            <clear/><!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
            <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>             
            <add ipAddress="MY IP" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>                              
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
```

I've searched for a solution but couldn't get anything to work. 
What I can see ipSecurity needs to be unlocked in ApplicationHost.config but I can't figure out how to do this at their Azures websites solution.

So I really hope someone can help me out or further to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You unlock web config sections by creating a startup file (startup.cmd for instance) and in its properties, select "Copy to output always" and then invoke this in your service definition like so:

```
<Startup><Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple"/></Startup>
```

And then in your startup.cmd run something like this:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe unlock config /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
```

Note that some sections can be unlocked and others can't so you might need to unlock the highest level or a level or two below it depending!

Comment: The question is about Azure Websites, not Azure cloud services. It's still a good answer, but not for this question.